# expected Exception but nothing was raised using Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to pass this last test: trying raise an exception I can't make it work
**My error-log:**

1) VideoSearch find then whole collection of samplers  failing  complains if there is not any RIGHT match
     Failure/Error: expect(vs.find_all_by_title(2343)).to raise_error
       expected Exception but nothing was raised

My code:

```
class VideoSearch

  attr_accessor :title, :samplers

  def initialize(params)
    @title = params
    @samplers = []    
  end

  def find_all_by_title(title)
    return [] if title.blank?
    Video.where(title: title).first
  end

  def find_the_whole_collection(title)  
    if find_all_by_title(title)
      sampler = find_all_by_title(title)
      @samplers = [sampler] #add the video as the first sample
    else
      raise Exception
      return false # it's false if there 's not any match!
    end
  end
end
```

My spec:

```
describe 'find then whole collection of samplers ' do
  let(:v1) { v1 = Video.create( title: 2345 ) }
  let(:vs) { VideoSearch.new v1.title }
  let(:sample) { vs.find_all_by_title(v1.title) }

  context 'failing' do
    before :each do
      vs.stub(:find_all_by_title).and_return(nil)
    end

    it ' complains if there is not any RIGHT match ' do
      expect(vs.find_all_by_title(2343)).to raise_error
    end
  end     
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your before block is stubbing out `:find_all_by_title` and returning nil, so it will not raise an error. A stub basically means 'if this method is called, instead do this', so all your code will not be run when stubbed. To get your code to work, remove the before_block. Also, when testing for unfound items, convention is to pass an `id` of `-1`, so your tests could look like:

```
context 'failing' do
  it 'complains if there is not any RIGHT match' do
    expect( vs.find_all_by_title(-1) ).to raise_error
  end
end
```

Additionally, you shouldn't raise `Exception`, you should at the very least by raising `StandardError` (or, really, a subclass of `StandardError` that is more descriptive of what you are doing. Perhaps, make a subclass of `StandardError` called `TitleNotFoundError`?).

Also, you have redundant code in your `find_whole_collection` method:

```
if find_all_by_title(title)
  sampler = find_all_by_title(title)
```

can be shortened to:

```
if sampler = find_all_by_title(title)
```

If you assign a variable a nil value in an `if` statement, it will return false, so you only have to call `find_all_by_title` once.

Lastly, your `find_all_by_title` method returns an empty array `[]` if blank, but `nil` if not found -- this could create problems (for instance, your `@samples` instance variable will contain `[[]]` if no title is passed).

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right path. Now I have a question regarding Stubbing: " so all your code will not be run when stubbed. " that was my actually point here to not run the code for ":find_all_by_title" and make it false so I could get in the 'else part of the if-statement? but maybe is not the right way? but of course ypu could also add a falsy value like you are doing right?

Comment: my test is not passing though?

Comment: Why are you calling `vs.find_all_by_title` then? You should be calling `find_the_whole_collection` and then stub `find_all_by_title`. But your tests are both stubbing and then calling the stubbed method expecting it to return something other than what your stub returns.

Comment: Read your test. You stub `find_all_by_title` and return `nil`, and then your test is `expect find_all_by_title to raise an error`.

Comment: I have had issues with expecting errors because `expect` needs a block. Try `expect { ...code()...}.to raise_error` maybe it will work but I have no clue why I have had to do this in my specs.